# Dogtag CA after installation

Tags: fedora, authentication, webserver, key-authentication, certificates

After Dogtag 10 installation(step by step by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3eElJAz7lU) when I open Admin (https://localhost.localdomain:8443/ca/agent/ca/) I get following error

> Problem Processing Your Request
>
> The Certificate Manager encountered an unexpected error while
>   processing your request. The following is a detailed message of the
>   error that occurred.
>
> ```
> You did not provide a valid certificate for this operation
> ```
>
> Please consult your local administrator for further assistance. The
>   Certificate System logs may provide further information.

In tutorials for older versions of dogtag I found that after configuration with pkicreate command it shows link to /ca/agent with some param "?pin=1asdkajsjk1421" but i newer version of dogtag I don't have that command and all configuration is done by pkispawn

pkispawn create 3 files:
ca_admin.cert ,
ca_admin.cert.der ,
ca_admin_cert.p12

but when I add them to firefox and to /etc/pki/ca-trust/sources/anchors and run update-ca-trust I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add p12 private key to firefox.
that help me a lot: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28385_01/en/E28378/html/STA102_Config_Iden_Mgmt_RACF.09.08.htm